# Ubuntu 19.04 Custom Shortcut Window Unfocused

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, shortcuts

In Ubuntu 19.04, I have set a custom shortcut for emacs from Settings > Keyboard. When I press the shortcut it works, but the window is unfocused, that is, behind my existing focused windows. I have to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to focus the window / switch to it.

I would like to simply have the shortcut focus the window. When I press my terminal shortcut this works as expected.

I couldn't find any information related to this.

Comment: The problem is that, unless you are focused on a specific window, the shortcut doesn't work? Would a suitable solution be something that when you use the shortcut, first focus on the specific window, and then run whatever it was meant to run originally?

Comment: @Podesta Sorry, to clarify. The shortcut always works. But the new window that popups from the shortcut is always unfocused. I would like this new window to the focused window after the shortcut keys are pressed.